# Are there infinitely many primes $p_n$ for which $p_n< 2n$?

Tags: prime-numbers

I am working in some calculations and I found this kind of problem. That is, 
are there infinitely many primes $p_n$ for which $p_n< 2n$ ? 
I think the answer is no, but I dont have a formal explanation.

Comment: I don't know if I precisely understand what you mean, but there are only four primes (2,3,5,7) strictly smaller than $10 = 2 \cdot 5$. This seems to contradict your statement.

Comment: Demophilus , thank you for your answer. But could you prove that the statment holds only for the primes that you have indicated?

Answer (score 5):

First note that $p_5=11>2\cdot 5=10$.

And if $n\geq 5$ and $p_n>2n$, it follows that
$$ p_{n+1}\geq p_n+2>2n+2=2(n+1) $$
so by induction $p_m>2m$ for all $m\geq 5$.